# Proper JSON Output of an Array with a Single Item?

Tags: arrays, json

What is the spec for JSON output of an array with a single item in the array?

Is it:

```
{"people":{"person":[{"id":1,"name":"jimbob"}]}}
```

Or:

```
{"people":{"person":{"id":1,"name":"jimbob"}}}
```

I know the JSON spec for multiple items in an array is:

```
{"people":{"person":[{"id":1,"name":"jimbob"},{"id":2,"name":"bettysue"}]}}
```

but I can't seem to find a spec for what a how a single item in an array should be represented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the first one --

```
{"people":{"person":[{"id":1,"name":"jimbob"}]}}
```

Otherwise it would be an object, not an array.

---

Incidentally, it seems like it would make more sense to remove the "person" object (seems redundant):

```
{"people":[{"id":1,"name":"jimbob"}]}
```

Comment: I would agree with you that if this were static output, it would make sense to remove the "person" object.  This is actually output from an API that typically returns multiple "people", but in this particular case is only returning one.

Comment: @user1210433 if that's what their API is returning, it seems incorrect.  It means you'd need a hackish check on the client side like `people.person.constructor == Array` to test whether `people.person` is an array or an object.

Comment: yep - that's exactly what I thought, but wanted to make sure before filing a bug.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Actually all of them return objects.

To return an array you would need to use something like:

[{"id":1,"name":"Harry"},{"id":2,"name":"Sally"}]